# Is it possible to write a function Int -> NatSing n, where NatSing is a singleton type of peano numbers?

Tags: haskell, types, gadt

Apologies for the vague title, here's some context: http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/issue221.pdf

The GADTs article in the above issue introduces a Nat type, and a NatSing type for use in various type-level list functions (concat, !!, head, repeat, etc). For a couple of these functions it's necessary to create type families for defining + and < on the Nat type.

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

data NatSing (n :: Nat) where
    ZeroSing :: NatSing Zero
    SuccSing :: NatSing n -> NatSing (Succ n)

data List (n :: Nat) a where
    Nil  :: List n a
    Cons :: a -> List n a -> List (Succ n) a
```

Anyways, I have written a function "list" that converts an ordinary `[a]` into a `List n a`, for convenience to the caller. This requires the length of the list as input, much like `repeat` (from the linked article):

```
list :: [a] -> NatSing n -> List n a
list []      ZeroSing    = Nil
list (x:xs) (SuccSing n) = Cons x (list xs n)
list _       _           = error "length mismatch"
```

It would be nice to utilize a helper function `toNatSing :: Int -> NatSing n`, so the above can be written as

```
list :: [a] -> List n a
list xs = list' xs (toNatSing $ length xs)
  where
    list' :: [a] -> NatSing n -> List n a
    list' = ... -- same as before, but this time I simply "know" the function is no longer partial
```

Is it possible to write such a function `toNatSing`? I've been wrestling with types and haven't come up with anything yet.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot write such a function.

A function of type

```
Int -> NatSing n
```

says that it can transform any integer into a *polymorphic* `NatSing`. But there is no polymorphic `NatSing`.

What you seem to want here is to have `n` determined by the incoming `Int`. That'd be a dependent type:

```
(n :: Int) -> NatSing n
```

Such a thing isn't possible in Haskell. You'd have to use Agda or Idris or another dependently typed language. The hack with singletons is exactly Haskell's way to get around this. If you want to make a distinction based on a value, you have to lift the value to the type level, which is what `NatSing` is.

You could write a function that returns a `NatSing` for *some* `n`, by wrapping the `n` up in an existential type:

```
data ExNatSing where
  ExNatSing :: NatSing n -> ExNatSing
```

But this wouldn't give you much benefit in practice. By wrapping the `n` up, you lose all information about it, and cannot make decisions based on it later.

By exactly the same argument, you can also not hope to define a function

```
list :: [a] -> List n a
```

The only approach you can use to save yourself some typing work is to define a type class that construct the `NatSing` value automatically:

```
class CNatSing (n :: Nat) where
  natSing :: NatSing n

instance CNatSing Zero where
  natSing = ZeroSing

instance CNatSing n => CNatSing (Succ n) where
  natSing = SuccSing natSing
```

Then, you can say:

```
list :: CNatSing n => [a] -> List n a
list xs = list' xs natSing
  where
    list' :: [a] -> NatSing n -> List n a
    list' = ... -- same as before, but still partial
```

Here, the type context you use this in makes GHC fill in the right `NatSing`. However, this function is *still* partial, because still the caller of the function can choose at what `n` to use this. If I want to use a `[Int]` of length `3` as a `List (Succ Zero) Int` it's going to crash.

Again, you could wrap this up in an existential instead:

```
data SomeList a where
  SomeList :: NatSing n -> List n a -> SomeList a
```

Then you could write

```
list :: [a] -> SomeList a
list []       = SomeList ZeroSing Nil
list (x : xs) = case list xs of
                  SomeList n xs -> SomeList (SuccSing n) (x : xs')
```

Again, the benefit is small, but in contrast to `ExNatSing`, there at least is one: you now can temporarily unwrap a `SomeList` and pass it to functions that operate on a `List n a`, getting type-system guarantees on how the length of the list is transformed by these functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you want looks something like (Int -> (exists n . NatSing n)), where `n` is unknown ahead of time.  You could do that with something like (untested):

```
data AnyNatSing where
  AnyNatSing :: NatSing n -> AnyNatSing

toNatSing :: Int -> AnyNatSing
toNatSing n
  | n > 0 = case toNatSing (n - 1) of
      AnyNatSing n -> AnyNatSing (SuccSing n)
  | otherwise = AnyNatSing ZeroSing
```

Comment: This would be very roundabout as `AnyNatSing` is basically just a positive-integer type.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I'm not sure I call it "roundabout" when it's the closest thing to the OP's desire that's possible at all in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Louis Wassermann, the closest match to what you want is an existential wrapper that makes `NatSing` monomorphic from the outside.

I consider that pretty useless though, since it basically just throws away the type-checking of lengths and you're left with a dumb standard integer type. There are easier ways to to that, like, using a dumb standard integer type and ordinary Haskell lists...

But there's one alternative that's perhaps not quite so useless. Remember that it's pretty much equivalent if you return some value `x` from a function, or instead pass a higher-order and *call* that with `x`; I think lisps particularly like such continuation-passing tricks.

For your example, you need a function that's able to accept *any* length-type of lists. Well, such functions certainly exist, e.g. a scalar product that requires two lists of equal length, but doesn't care what the length is. And it then returns a simple monomorphic number. For simplicity's sake, let's consider an even simpler `sum` on your list type:

```
sumSing :: Num a => List (n::Nat) a -> a
sumSing Nil = 0
sumSing (Cons x ls) = x + sumSing ls
```

Then you can do:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes     #-}

onList :: (forall n . CNatSing n => List n a -> b) -> [a] -> b
f`onList`l = f (list l)
```

(`list` being kosmicus' variant with the `CNatSing` class constraint) and call it like

```
sumSing `onList` [1,2,3]
```

...which is of course in itself no more useful than the existential solution (which, I think, actually desugars to something similar to this `RankN` stuff). But you can do more here, like the scalar product example – providing two lists and actually ensuring through the type system they have the same length. This would be far uglier with existentials: you'd basically need a seperate `TwoEqualLenLists` type.